# gcc arm -mcpu extensions not recognized

Tags: gcc, arm

I'm using `arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc.exe (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2015.05-16) 4.9.2` that comes with the `Xilinx` toolchain for the `Zynq`. I specify the `-mcpu=cortex-a9` option. However I want to disable the use of floating point and co-processors such such as Neon. So I add the extensions for the mcpu option : `-mcpu=cortex-a9+nofp+nosimd`. However the compiler does not recognize this extensions

```
arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mcpu=cortex-a9+nofp'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or this compiler version does not implement this extensions?

Comment: I don't think you read my question attentively. I am asking about the extensions for the mcpu option described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Why mention the option to generate thumb code?